# Random numbers in a grid

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a 15x15 grid with every element being a random number between 0 and 5. why isn't this working?

```
import random
board = []

for row in range(15):
    board.append([])
    for column in range(15):
        board[row].append(random.randint(0,5))

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(' ').join(row)
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: `print(' ').join(row)` --> `print(' '.join(row))`?

Comment: @m_callens: either none (they didn't call `print_board()`, or `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`, or `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'`, depending on the Python version..

Comment: im getting the rows all together instead of creating a new line

Comment: @Yuiop: you can't, not with the code you posted. You get no output at all with that code, since you don't call `print_board`. Can you show us what output you *do* get? You are getting downvoted because a) you didn't really follow our [ask] guidelines, and b) didn't provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what *does* happen, or what you expected to happen.

First of all, your code doesn't show that you called `print_board()`. You may want to do that:

```
print_board(board)
```

But then you'll get an error. If you are using Python 2, you'd see:

```
>>> print_board(board)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in print_board
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

because `str.join()` only takes strings as input, not integers, which your `row` lists contain.

In Python 3 you'd see:

```
>>> print_board(board)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in print_board
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'
```

because you called the `print()` function and then tried to join the return value of that call.

Either way, you can fix either error by using `str.join()` correctly, mapping all integer values to strings, and passing the result to `print()` (in Python 2, the outer parentheses are ignored in this case):

```
print(' '.join([str(i) for i in row]))
```

With that fix, printing your board shows you managed to generate the board correctly:

```
>>> def print_board(board):
...     for row in board:
...         print(' '.join(map(str, row)))
...
>>> print_board(board)
2 1 1 4 0 5 3 2 1 0 5 3 4 1 3
4 1 0 1 4 4 3 3 5 0 0 0 4 5 2
2 0 3 3 2 4 0 1 0 3 2 3 3 0 2
2 0 5 2 2 3 4 1 3 1 4 4 0 1 5
4 0 4 3 3 5 4 4 0 4 5 2 2 2 4
2 0 1 4 5 1 3 0 4 2 4 1 4 5 1
5 5 0 1 4 3 0 3 2 2 4 1 1 0 3
4 2 1 1 3 1 4 5 0 5 1 4 1 0 2
1 3 4 1 4 1 2 0 0 4 1 5 4 3 5
1 0 3 1 2 2 0 0 4 1 5 5 4 4 0
3 5 3 1 5 0 3 4 5 5 4 0 3 1 4
0 2 5 5 0 2 1 3 0 0 2 2 2 0 3
4 1 1 1 4 4 1 5 1 5 3 1 2 5 2
2 5 5 2 1 4 4 2 5 5 2 1 3 2 2
3 1 1 5 3 0 4 5 2 1 1 2 3 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't str.join with integers, only strings.  Try change this line

```
print(' ').join(row)
```

To this:

```
print(' '.join([str(s) for s in row]))
```

Comment: im still getting the rows all together